# Django Rest Framework 'can't set attribute' in APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint, **CompanyDefaultView** class that inherits **APIView** and **AURPostCompIdMixin** classes.

using this endpoint i get `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error.

this is all code in one file

```
import logging
from abc import ABC

from rest_framework import status, serializers
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

HEADER_USER_STATUS = 'User-Status'

USER_STATUS_NOT_EXIST = 'not-exist'
USER_STATUS_EXIST = 'exist'
USER_STATUS_EXIST_NOT_ACTIVE = 'not-active'
USER_STATUS_EXIST_ACTIVE = 'active'


class RspPropsMixin:
    _response = None

    @property
    def response(self):
        return self._response

    _stat_code = None

    _rsp_headers = {}

    @property
    def stat_code(self):
        return self._stat_code

    @property
    def rsp_headers(self):
        return self._rsp_headers

    def _set_rsp_props(self, response, header_key, header, stat_code):

        self._response = response
        if header is not None:
            self._rsp_headers[header_key] = header
        self._stat_code = stat_code

    def set_rsp(self, response=None, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, header=None,
                stat_code=status.HTTP_200_OK):

        self._set_rsp_props(response, header_key, header, stat_code)

    def set_rsp_msg(self, msg, desc=None, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, header=None,
                    stat_code=status.HTTP_200_OK):

        response = {'msg': msg}
        if desc is not None:
            response['desc'] = desc
        self._set_rsp_props(response, header_key, header, stat_code)

    def add_header(self, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, *, header):
        self._rsp_headers[header_key] = header



class AURMixin(RspPropsMixin):
    """
    AuthenticatedUserRequestMixin class
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    _comp_id = None
    _ruser = None


    @property
    def comp_id(self):
        return self._comp_id

    @property
    def ruser(self):
        return self._ruser

    def handle_valid_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement handle_valid_request method!")

    def handle_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement handle_request method!")


class PostMethodMixin:
    """
    mixin class for AURMixin
    """

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("in PostMethodMixin!")
        self.handle_request(request, request.POST, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(self.response, self.stat_code)

       
def company_exists(comp_id):
    # return Company.objects.filter(id=comp_id).exists()
    return True


class AURCompIdMixin(AURMixin, ABC):

    def handle_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        serilaizer = CompIdSerializer(data=http_method_data)
        serilaizer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        comp_id = serilaizer.validated_data['comp_id']

        if not company_exists(comp_id):
            msg = "ther is not company with this id!"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
        else:
            self._ruser = request.user
            self._comp_id = comp_id
            self.handle_valid_request(request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs)


class AURPostCompIdMixin(AURCompIdMixin, PostMethodMixin, ABC):
    pass


class CompIdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comp_id = serializers.IntegerField()


class CompanyDefaultView(APIView, AURPostCompIdMixin):

    def handle_valid_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CompIdSerializer(data=request.POST)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        comp_id = serializer.validated_data['comp_id']
        if not company_exists(comp_id):
            msg = "no company msg"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
        else:
            msg = "success msg"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
```

and this is the stack trace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-test-YQhu4ov0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-test-YQhu4ov0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-test-YQhu4ov0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-test-YQhu4ov0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-test-YQhu4ov0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 511, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I'v tried several things and did not work.

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a conflict between **_response** in **RspPropsMixin** class and response in **rest_framework.response.Response** class.

If you override **response** method by changing **_response** to **_rsp**:

```
@property
def response(self):
    return self._response
```

to

```
@property
def rsp(self)
    return self._rsp
```

it works.

full code:

```
import logging
from abc import ABC

from rest_framework import status, serializers
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

HEADER_USER_STATUS = 'User-Status'

USER_STATUS_NOT_EXIST = 'not-exist'
USER_STATUS_EXIST = 'exist'
USER_STATUS_EXIST_NOT_ACTIVE = 'not-active'
USER_STATUS_EXIST_ACTIVE = 'active'


class RspPropsMixin:
    _rsp = None

    @property
    def rsp(self):
        return self._rsp

    _stat_code = None

    _rsp_headers = {}

    @property
    def stat_code(self):
        return self._stat_code

    @property
    def rsp_headers(self):
        return self._rsp_headers

    def _set_rsp_props(self, response, header_key, header, stat_code):

        self._rsp = response
        if header is not None:
            self._rsp_headers[header_key] = header
        self._stat_code = stat_code

    def set_rsp(self, response=None, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, header=None,
                stat_code=status.HTTP_200_OK):

        self._set_rsp_props(response, header_key, header, stat_code)

    def set_rsp_msg(self, msg, desc=None, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, header=None,
                    stat_code=status.HTTP_200_OK):

        response = {'msg': msg}
        if desc is not None:
            response['desc'] = desc
        self._set_rsp_props(response, header_key, header, stat_code)

    def add_header(self, header_key=HEADER_USER_STATUS, *, header):
        self._rsp_headers[header_key] = header


class AURMixin(RspPropsMixin):
    """
    AuthenticatedUserRequestMixin class
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    _comp_id = None
    _ruser = None

    @property
    def comp_id(self):
        return self._comp_id

    @property
    def ruser(self):
        return self._ruser

    def handle_valid_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement handle_valid_request method!")

    def handle_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement handle_request method!")


class PostMethodMixin:
    """
    mixin class for AURMixin
    """

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("in PostMethodMixin!")
        self.handle_request(request, request.POST, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(self.rsp, self.stat_code)


def company_exists(comp_id):
    # return Company.objects.filter(id=comp_id).exists()
    return True


class AURCompIdMixin(AURMixin, ABC):

    def handle_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        serilaizer = CompIdSerializer(data=http_method_data)
        serilaizer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        comp_id = serilaizer.validated_data['comp_id']

        if not company_exists(comp_id):
            msg = "ther is not company with this id!"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
        else:
            self._ruser = request.user
            self._comp_id = comp_id
            self.handle_valid_request(request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs)


class AURPostCompIdMixin(AURCompIdMixin, PostMethodMixin, ABC):
    pass


class CompIdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comp_id = serializers.IntegerField()


class CompanyDefaultView(APIView, AURPostCompIdMixin):

    def handle_valid_request(self, request, http_method_data, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CompIdSerializer(data=request.POST)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        comp_id = serializer.validated_data['comp_id']
        if not company_exists(comp_id):
            msg = "no company msg"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
        else:
            msg = "success msg"
            self.set_rsp_msg(msg)
```